# mysql - select data from multiple tables with different structures

Tags: mysql

I have an inventory database where every item ID comes from a single source.  Presently the primary table (cp_partlist) looks something like:

```
- PK_PartID
- TableName
```

I then have separate tables for each type of item, and each table has different data.  For example, I might have a table for bolts which has:

```
- FK_PartID
- ThreadType
- Length
- DriveType
```

and a table for washers which has:

```
- FK_PartID
- OD
- ID
- Thickness
```

If I want the specific info for a given PartID, right now I am looking up the table name in the primary table, and then using that to get the specific data that I want from the correct table.

It seems like there should be a more direct approach.  I tried using a LEFT JOIN like:

```
    SELECT * FROM cp_partlist AS pl
      LEFT JOIN bolts ON pl.PK_PartID=bolts.FK_PartID
      LEFT JOIN washers ON pl.PK_PartID=washers.FK_PartID
    WHERE PK_PartID=400004
```

This works except that I end up with a column from every table, not just the table I am interested in.  I can't specify the column name because it is different for each table.

Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: what result do you need?

Comment: How does your application know which column to look for the results in?  Does it already know what fields it should be looking for based on the PartID, or does it just look for non-null values?

Comment: What does a bolt and washer having the same partid indicate?

Comment: It would help if you can post the expected outcome that you need.. I'm not sure I understand what `I end up with a column from every table, not just the table I am interested in. I can't specify the column name because it is different for each table.` would mean.. So some expected sample outcomes would help tons..

Comment: The bolt and washer do not have the same PartID; but they do draw from the same auto_increment number.  For example, if I create a new bolt for inventory, it would have ID 1.  If I then create a new nut, it would have ID 2, and so on.  All the categories draw from the same auto_increment number so that there are no repetitions.
The problem this creates is that if I only have a number, I don't know what category of part that represents.  So if I have a parts list that says to get item 400004, and I need more info, then I want to find the specifics for that item.

Comment: The type of item determines the result I want.  If it is a washer, then I would expect to see only the fields in the washer table (OD, ID, & thickness).  If it is a bolt, then I want to know only the fields in the bolt table.  But there might be 10 fields in one table and only 3 in another.
With my left join sql above, the table columns are: PK_PartID, TableName, FK_PartID, ThreadType, Length, DriveType, FK_PartID, OD, ID, Thickness (every column from every table).  I only want the columns specific to the type of item I have the number for.

Answer (score 0):

I fi understand you question correctly, you wish to retreive data from your cp_partlist table joined with bolts and washers tables, however you wish to show only four columns, not eight as you are currently getting.

This can be acheived with a `UNION` statement, however the field types for each of the `JOIN`ed columns MUST be of the same type.

So a query like this can be used (if the above criteria is met)

```
SELECT pl.*, bolts.FKPartID,bolts.ThreadType AS Data1,bolts.Length AS Data2, bolts.Drivetype as Data3  FROM cp_partlist AS pl 
LEFT JOIN bolts ON pl.PK_PartID=bolts.FK_PartID 
WHERE PK.PartID=400004

    UNION

SELECT pl.*,washers.FKPartID,washers.OD AS Data1,washers.ID as Data2, Washers.thickness as Data3 FROM cp_partlist as pl 
LEFT JOIN washers ON pl.PK_partID = washers.FK_partID 
WHERE PK.PartID=400004
```

Note that this will result in a table with the following columns:

```
PK_PartID,Tablename,FK_PartID,Data1,Data2,Data3
```

Comment: The fields will not be of the same type, nor will there be an equivalent number of fields in each table.

Comment: One way to do this is to cast every field to a varchar, or have a 'definitions' table that defines the correct table for each AutoID. Then in the application logic you can simply build your SQL and select the correct columns according to the requested ID.